# android apk is not able to create text file on physical device

Tags: android

I generated a APK file for my Android app. In this app, a local text file is created and updated. The app is running fine on emulator without any additional permission. But, when apk is installed on my mobile, there is no data related to the created local text file.I have give all permissions,

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: what's  physical device android version?

Comment: Android 10 is my physical device version and Android Studio version is 4.2.1,

Comment: Do you know about scoped storage?